# this is defined, but children and querySelector fail for custom element

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, custom-element

I have a custom element (input-date) inside another custom element (edit-table). When I go to assign the value to the input-date, inside the 'set value' class member function i log:

```
 console.log(this)
```

prints out the element

```
<input-date id=​"cell" style=​"height:​ 100%;​ width:​ 300px;​">
  ​<input id=​"input" placeholder=​"mm/​dd/​yyyy, hh:​mm am/​pm" style=​"font-family:​ "Open Sans", sans-serif;​ height:​ 100%;​ width:​ 100%;​ text-align:​ left;​ font-size:​ 18px;​ border:​ 2px;​ border-radius:​ 5px;​ padding:​ 5px;​">​
</input-date>​
```

but when i do

```
 console.log(this.children);
```

and

```
 console.log(this.querySelector('#input'));
```

I get 'null'.

the function with 'this' is inside 'set value' of my input-date class

```
class InputDate extends HTMLElement
{
...
connectedCallback()
{
  var input = document.createElement('Input');
  input.id = 'input';
  this.appendChild(input);
}
set value(val)
{
  //val should be a date object 
  var i = this.querySelector('#input');
  if(i && val)
  {
    i.value = val.toLocaleString();
  }
  console.log(i,val,this, this.childNodes);
}
...
customElements.define('input-date',InputDate);
```

note: also if its relevant, my_date.value = some_date; (the part that calls the 'set value' class member function) happens in a completion block from an XMLHTTPRequest to an API.

the input-date is created inside another custom element called edit-table.

so i set the users in 'edit-table'

```
get_users(function(r)
{
  if(r.hasOwnProperty('error_message'))
  {
    alert(r.error_message);
  }
  else
  {
    var table   = document.getElementById('edit-table');
    table.users = r.users;  
  }
});
```

then under 'edit-tables' 'set users', i create an 'input-date' element and try to assign the date from the server, (which is Wed Feb 08 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500)

```
class EditUsers extends HTMLElement
...
set users(users)
{  
  ...
  var check  = document.createElement('input-date');
  check.value = new Date('Wed Feb 08 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500');
}
customElements.define('edit-table',EditTable);
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us more context? We have no idea what `this` is or anything.

Comment: Is your console.log inside a function? If so than the reference to 'this' may be set to the scope of the function and not the outer code. Can you tell me what 'this' is before you attempt to log this.children or your querySelector?

Comment: absolutely. added more code and context

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/y858qkwt/2/ Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow! Cant believe it. i've been making this mistake for years now and am still doing it....

i need to do 'appendChild' of my custom-element BEFORE doing

```
 my_element.value = new Date();
```

because until 'appendChild' is called, the 'connectedCallback()' is not called yet, and therefore the 'input' element is not appended to my custom-element yet, and therefore the 'querySelector' cant find the child yet.

thanks @mickers, I didnt want to bog down the details, but this is what happened. Hopefully helps someone